# Flexbox, limit images heigh/width within space available

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a fixed size wrapper consisting of:

- Header that is sized to the whats inside
- Footer that is fixed size
- Content container that should use the remaining space of the wrapper

The problem occurs with images. I would like for images to resize to fit the content container both in height and width. Right now images overflow the wrapper in height.

Here is the code. The wide image is acting correct, resizing to fit, but the long giraf is not.
In the following fiddle **overflow is set to scroll to debug**. The endgoal is no overflow.
https://jsfiddle.net/sghp68r0/

A not so flexible solution would simply be to give the imageFit class a height like

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.imageFit {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 150px;
}
```

But this I would rather avoid hardcoding the height.

My goal is that it looks like this (no overflow): [image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can fix overflow in flexbox by setting height of the containing div to 0 (for safari it should be min-height: 0). Have a look at this example. If you remove height breaks.

https://jsfiddle.net/oz20qgw9/

```
.content {
  background-color: green;
  flex:2;
  height: 0; //THIS IS THE KEY!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if i am right you want this. Please do let me know.

Drag the height in fiddle you see the images are adjusting with heigh.

Here is my fiddle link:-

https://jsfiddle.net/exa3y7w9/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Sized to content <br />
    Sized to content <br />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/10/22/24/wide-format-2839089_960_720.jpg">
    </div>
    <div> 2 images and some text that fills remaining space </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="http://clipart-library.com/data_images/258951.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    There is some text in fixed size container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct. That is exactly what I want! Very cool solution. That does however force me to either fix the height of the header or to get the height with javascript and dynamically set the calc. 

If it helps there is some additional information. There will ALWAYS be 2 images, and the images will ALWAYS have the same amount of space available to them (wether they use it or not). Check this solution, this however is really hacky with the height:0 in 'content' class. https://jsfiddle.net/oz20qgw9/

Comment: Firstly thank you,
your's solution is also good but it's only works when you give some specific height to outer wrapper, otherwise the content section don't appear as it's height is 0px;

Comment: If you are ok to give outer wrapper fixed height, then this is also a good solution for your problem.
thankyou.